# Docker: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate' Thanks in advance

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I am creating a python program that will allow me to have a dashboard to check on stocks and different financial indicators pulled from yahoo finance. " HELP. Thanks in advance!!

I tried to import a module named "tabulate" to allow me to format the information nicely into a table. But when I added it to the requirements file it doesn't work, I even tried running it straight in the docker-compose file but it still says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'

!!Python File (this is what makes the error)!!

```py
import yfinance as yf
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
```

!!Docker File!!

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY ./src ./src


CMD ["python3", "src/main.py" ]
```

!!docker-compose.yaml!!

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: python3 src/main.py
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

!!requirements.txt!!

```
yfinance
tabulate
pandas
```

I tried to import a module named "tabulate" to allow me to format the information nicely into a table. But when I added it to the requirements file it doesn't work, I even tried running it straight in the docker-compose file but it still says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'

!!"docker build ." output!!

```
[+] Building 1.2s (10/10) FINISHED                         docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 242B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim        1.1s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim@sha256:8f64a67710f3d981  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 3.94kB                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY ./requirements.txt ./                                0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt        0.0s
 => CACHED [5/5] COPY ./src ./src                                          0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:db3805b9c6284cc3fa65db601b3a5c51553f2523f0fa9  0.0s

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/qubwln0smtsm1nqr2nchwlwnk

What's Next?
  1. Sign in to your Docker account → docker login
  2. View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
```

!!docker build . -t test1 output!!

```
[+] Building 1.1s (10/10) FINISHED                                             docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 242B                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim                            1.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 293B                                                              0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim@sha256:8f64a67710f3d981cf3008d6f9f1dbe61acc  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY ./requirements.txt ./                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                            0.0s
 => CACHED [5/5] COPY ./src ./src                                                              0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                         0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                        0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:db3805b9c6284cc3fa65db601b3a5c51553f2523f0fa90bf4fd488d3af06cd86   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test1                                                       0.0s

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/xsr0m6u083ltp0yd3lry79j9y

What's Next?
  1. Sign in to your Docker account → docker login
  2. View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
```

!!Output for docker build --no-cache .!!

```
[+] Building 15.6s (10/10) FINISHED                                            docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 242B                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim                            0.3s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11-slim@sha256:8f64a67710f3d981cf3008d6f9f1dbe61acc  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 293B                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                  0.0s
 => [3/5] COPY ./requirements.txt ./                                                           0.0s
 => [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                  14.7s
 => [5/5] COPY ./src ./src                                                                     0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                         0.5s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                        0.5s 
 => => writing image sha256:9e1b379dba0593ebe97344053b3314557a7f22037f3f3981d4a652f17ce3eb79   0.0s 
                                                                                                    
View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/x2bwqvnfu70pfrq8kpgrbch01
```

Comment: Are there any errors when `pip install` runs as part of building the image? At the very least, could you show the output when you build the image?

Comment: I've tried to simulate your setup, created the exact `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose`, `requirements.txt` and `src/main.py` but I cannot reproduce the error. I've started the app with `docker compose up`

Comment: Did you rebuild the image after you edited your requirements file? Although docker-compose should build from scratch with the build:. command.

Comment: What is the directory the requirements.txt is located in?

Comment: @TedPossible The same directory as the Dockerfile and docker-compose

Comment: @ndc85430 just added it to the post

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have to run it with docker-compose run app (I think) because I hadn't been able to use the python input() function without it. maybe that is the issue?

Comment: It's using a cached version of the image, I would recommend deleting the image and rebuilding

Comment: @TedPossible I do docker build . if that is what you mean, I have to run it with docker-compose run app ( I think so) or else the python input() function throws an error

Comment: @TedPossible okay, thank you! How would I do that exactly, I don't want to mess it up, also, quick question, I've been getting the error "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/joshuawalter/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" if I don't have the guy version of docker running, how do I fix that (sorry I don't know why but my whole setup is jacked up)

Comment: Are you certain your requirements.txt is in the directory it's looking for it.  Which would be the directory you are running the build from?

Comment: @TedPossible I am running Mac OS Ventura 13.3, I am certain the requirements.txt is in the same folder that I am running the build command from

Comment: OK then you seem to be using Docker Desktop -- there should be a Docker icon on your top right hand corner of the screen in the menu bar

Comment: after you run the steps in my answer please post output of your docker build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output it appears you are using a cached version of the image and it does not include your modifications to requirements.txt

```
=> CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY ./requirements.txt ./                                0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt        0.0s
 => CACHED [5/5] COPY ./src ./src
```

You can either remove the docker image and then rebuild or use docker build with the --no-cache option or have docker-compose directly build without cache for you.

To find a list of your image names execute:

```
docker image ls
```

And then remove the image with:

```
docker image rm image-name
# Rebuild the image
```

To use the --no-cache option use the the following:

```
docker build --no-cache . -t image-name
```

Have docker-compose directly build image for you without cache:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up
```

Comment: the output is too long for the comments I will post it in the main post

Comment: I ran docker build . -t test1 after removing the old one

Comment: it's still showing cached.

Comment: try docker build --no-cache .

Comment: Just did, Ill add it to the post

Comment: I added instructions to rebuild directly with docker-compose to my this answer